# Maven Project: Java class does not get displayed as Java source?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created a Maven Project in Eclipse but if I create a Java class it is just added to `src/main/resources` and it not displayed as Java source code:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: rightclick, open with, select what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your creating class in wrong directory. Classes should be in `src/main/java` for source classes and `src/test/java` for test classes. Maven follows standard directory structure. [Check this link for more info](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: Hm, could this be a bug? I was trying that but either it told me that the directory is already there but I couldn't add anything or Eclipse told me that `src/main/java` does not exist. So I just opened the file browser, created it manually and there we go it works as it always did..

Comment: Ah and [by the way](http://www.troll.me/images2/grammar-correction-guy/youre.jpg).

Comment: Change the view to `Package View` on eclipse. You will see the folders `src/main/java` there

Comment: @StefanFalk From the next time, create new maven project using `maven-archetype-quickstart`. It will create standard structure for `Java application`. You can do this from command line using `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} 
   -DartifactId={project-name} 
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
   -DinteractiveMode=false`.